# How can I program a web-based GUI in node.js and make continuous calls to a c program?

Tags: c, node.js, user-interface

I think the title is pretty self explanatory.
Basically, I have a C program that utilizes a ton of data structures to do various tasks. The program has to be in C, and it doesn't have to have any GUI at all, but I want to make one because why not.

The program and the nodejs web server (if it was running one) would both be on the same, local machine. They'd be ran together by default and only by me. So my question is, is it realistic to try to develop a GUI in a language like Node.js, and make continuous calls to a C program?
How efficient or inefficient will it be? What are the drawbacks?

Like I said, I have to do the program in C. It's for a homework assignment, but I don't really want to try to program any UI in C. Any other methods would be fine as well. I can write in Python and Node.js and my OOP in C++ is good enough to have made a couple 2D programs in Direct2D.

EDIT 2: The program (whether it be the C program or the GUI) will eventually have to utilize a database in some way. So that can go into any possible answers rationale, if it means anything.

EDIT 3: 
What I am looking for in an answer: Yes/no it's possible, what language to use and why, and hopefully some library for the task.

Inefficiency: Given a "standard" machine (let's say an i5-337U @ 1.7 GHz, 6 GB DDR3 RAM), the interaction with the GUI (which would involve clicking, and the input would be sent to the C program as an argument, which would then do calculations on said input, all of which is simple math and there would be no more than 10 *simple* (add, mult, dvd, all <4 digit numbers) calculations for each input) should be complete, as in calculations complete and GUI updated with results of calculations, within a second or two.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what exactly the question is. If you're asking whether it's possible to do this, then the answer is yes. If you're asking whether it's inefficient, please elaborate on what kind of behaviour can be considered inefficient in this situation.

Comment: You could make a C program work as an HTTP server (so have its user interface be a Web interface), e.g. using some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my past experiences, I would try something like this:

**Frontend**

Create a frontend that does something, namely send messages to a RESTful server. This could be with jQuery or Angular or whatever framework you are comfortable with.

**Server side**

Create a Node server running on the same machine as your C program. Node handles web requests pretty well, and pick a framework like Express, Restify, Koa or others for your HTTP handling.

**C Program**

Then, talk to your C program in some way. You didn't mention anything in your post, but TCP is a common library you might find for your C project and you can just use the [core net libs](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

Alternatively, you could start your C program via Node and talk to it via stdin! Search around stack overflow for tips on how to do that, but that might be even easier than TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement are :

- a program without GUI written in C language
- the GUI, and the program will run on same machine

Unless Node.js is your predilection UI language, I won't use a WEB user interface, because it adds a high overhead and some complexity, specially if the server part has to push data to the interface.

The remaining is <del>experience</del> highly opinion based.

Python + Qt allows to generate easily very nice GUI programs, with all the power of Qt and the writing simplicity of Python. You have even a specialized IDE for that : [eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/). But depending on their experience, others will advice you to use other tools based on Tk/gtk, wxWindows, NET/mono, java/swing with the same arguments (or absence of argument) as mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

From my opinionated experience, your C program can be a command line based program which interacts with the outside world via STDIN/STDOUT.

The GUI program runs in the browser, utilizing all kinds of Javascript framework, such as Jquery, AngurlarJS, etc.

NodeJS (with ExpressJS) runs as a local HTTP server, being the perfect glue in between.

On one end, NodeJS `spawn` your C program as a child process and talks to it via STDIN/STDOUT.

On the other end, NodeJS talks HTTP/AJAX/WEBSOCKET to the GUI in the browser.

Several workarounds for your consideration:

1. GUI may send a lot of settings in JSON format to NodeJS, which will be difficult to "translate" into command line inputs for the C program. One way is to have NodeJS save the settings into a local JSON file and your C program parse that JSON file for input parameters on-the-fly.
2. GUI in the browser window can have some limitations, for example, not able to choose local files/folders. But NodeJS can `spawn` other simple GUI programs to pop up a file-choose-dialog window for that specific purpose. I made these simple GUI programs with AutoIt scripts, compiled to standalone exe.

Such a seemingly complicated kernel/front-end architecture has several benefits:

1. GUI frameworks becomes old-fashioned and obsolete quickly, not to mention the huge effort learning to program with them going to waste. (just to mention a few: Win32, MFC, WinForm, WPF). Nowadays browser is the new "virtual machine" to run-everywhere your GUI.  It is true that browser and Javascript frameworks are evolving much faster. But they are relatively easy to code and be fitted with a "new look".
2. Because of the fast evolving GUI code, good reason to separate the kernel from the GUI code. It's possible that years later, the kernel code can be fitted with different GUI code and still be functional.
3. Kernel code being command line (or console based) makes it easier to test/debug/deploy/extend ... (the whole unix philosophy)
4. The browser html/javascript code, nodejs, command line can all be potentially multi-platform (windows, linux, mac os x and mobile) and compiled, deployed very easily. (just file copy/paste, no installation)
5. local nodejs server serving at localhost can be tunneled outside via `ngrok` such that it becomes a real web app quite easily
6. [to be extended]